# перебор словаря в python

Tags: python

Как перебрать словарь чтобы выходило количество элементов в словаре

```
name = {'Имена': {
    'Максим',
    'Чаплин',
    'Вика',
    'Шрек'
}
```

Comment: Приведите пример словаря и желаемого вывода.

Comment: Чтобы получить количество элементов в словаре, его не обязательно перебирать.

Comment: Зачем такой «словарь»?

Comment: это пример просто

Comment: Это некорректный пример.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Внутренные скобки должны быть или обыкновенными (для кортежи) или квадратными (для списка):

```
In[4]: name = {'Имена': ('Максим', 'Чаплин', 'Вика', 'Шрек',) }
In[5]: number_of_elements = len(name['Имена'])
```

Так как ключ - `'Имена'`, то `name['Имена']` - его значение, т.е. кортеж

```
                  ('Максим', 'Чаплин', 'Вика', 'Шрек',)
```

Применяя функцию `len()` мы получим количество элементов кортежи.

Тест:

```
In[6]: print(number_of_elements)
```

Вывод:

> ```
> 4
> ```